# Does the NSF commonly ask for removing acknowledgments?

Tags: publications, funding, nsf

How frequent is the following scenario?

> A researcher on an NSF grant posts or publishes a paper which is thematically unrelated to the NSF grant, but acknowledges the grant for financial support. The NSF demands that the acknowledgment be removed.

Is this an extraordinary scenario, or is it considered normal? I have heard different accounts from different people.

Moreover, does this usually cause troubles to the researcher down the line, like extra scrutiny on their next NSF application?

Comment: I haven't heard of it happening - how would an author even be able to get the journal to remove funding information after publication? Also see [On the use of grant funds for extracurricular research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8873/17254) for evidence that NSF don't tend to complain if some unrelated research gets published. Now, if you don't produce *any* papers related to the research proposal there might be an issue.

Comment: I've never heard of this happening, and, at least in math, I really don't think they care much whether you're doing what you proposed, or not. They care about acknowledgement, and they care about (traditional) publications and such. I don't think anyone is checking this, anyway, until you "report"! For that matter, if you'll pardon me, not so many of the people permanently at NSF would be able to easily tell whether you've "strayed" or not, anyway. Of course, if you ask them directly, etc., you could possibly stir up trouble with some of the more naive/doctrinaire types...

Comment: Well, I am aware of it [happening once](https://quillette.com/2018/09/07/academic-activists-send-a-published-paper-down-the-memory-hole/#comments) to an article in press, so it definitely exists. What I'm wondering about is whether it's extraordinary or not.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, it is _alleged_ to have happened at least once; we only have one side of that story.

Comment: That situation strikes me as extraordinary (in a bad way) in several regards. Also, possibly more-to-the-point, if someone with a bit of power wants to deep-six you, they can probably manage it one way or another, finding _some_ bureaucratic justification, even if nonsensical... Just as citizens have civil rights until we're declared enemy combatants, etc. The issues are other than this, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett: My question is deliberately set in a more general setting; shining light on this particular situation is only part of what I'm trying to achieve. Also, I have heard at least one colleague claiming that this is *not* extraordinary and the NSF has recently been getting more anal about grant-driven research being to the point.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I've never heard of this happening, except for the single instance you cite, which wa exceptional in several other respects. Perhaps you could ask your colleague(s) for evidence, and then post it here as an answer.  Without concrete evidence that NSF is getting pickier, the only possible answer is "I've never heard of this happening, except for the single instance you cite."