# Acknowledge funding institute, sending and hosting universities

Tags: funding, acknowledgement, visiting

I have a question that is related to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/acknowledging-funding) and it is about a paper acknowledgements section.

I am an economist.
I am currently working in university "A." 
I am preparing a paper, and in this initial stage of the study I will visit the foreign university "B," where I will collect data.
For this visiting period, I am going to receive a travel grant from the third party institute "C," which covers both the travel and the stay abroad.

Within a few months, I shall leave my current university "A," so when the paper will be published (if it will be good enough, ça va sans dire) I will be in another university, maybe university "D."

Also, assume in university "D" I won't get any additional funding for this study.

Given this situation, which one of these four institutes will have to be thanked in the acknowledgements of this paper?

- the current university A
- the hosting university B
- the granting institute C
- the future university D (I think this won't have to be thanked; I have never seen anybody thanking her own university when this university does not provide any extra funds)

What is the academic bon ton in this case?

Comment: Thank the *people* at A, B, and D who helped you while you worked (if they helped you *with* the work, they will also be co-authors).

Comment: The granting institute "C" will have (at least!) provided you the means to collect the data for the study. Without institute "C", no data, and hence no paper. Hence they should be acknowledged, something along the lines of "Financial support in the data collection phase of this project was provided by institute 'C'". (Of course if your assumption in the fourth paragraph turns out to be wrong, this would have to be reworded...)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should distinguish *acknowledgements* from *affiliation*.  You should also generally act generously with acknowledgements, because giving acknowledgements doesn't generally detract from anything as long as you're honest about them.

So, in your case:

- Your affiliation is University A.  If you are at University D by the time the paper hits camera-ready, then you might add that affiliation too, as a dual affiliation.
- You definitely need to acknowledge the funding support of Institute C.  You may also want to acknowledge University B if the *organization* has given you support (as opposed to just individual faculty members).  For example, if the department loaned you facilities for doing your work, that would definitely merit acknowledgement in my book.
- Other people who helped significantly with the project (except within normal non-scientific job duties) should get co-authorship or acknowledgement.  Thus, a hosting faculty member at University B should appear in the paper, but the IT person at University B who fixed your computer would not.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the visit, B could constitute an affiliation too. If in doubt, ask your supervisor. That's what they're there for!